# Are there other use cases for PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT than the 'lightweight' pattern?

Tags: java, hibernate

I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277500/hibernate-polymorphism-explicit-annotation-doesnt-work/17278396#17278396) recently about why [PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/PolymorphismType.html) doesn't limit a query to the specifically requested class.  My research in to the answer made me question why there is such an annotation at all, and what it's good for.

The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-class) says the following:

> Explicit polymorphisms means that class instances will be returned only by queries that explicitly name that class. Queries that name the class will return only instances of subclasses mapped.

...and yet, as has been brought up on Stack Overflow [several times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=polymorphismtype.explicit%20not%20working), the phrasing is a bit confusing.  People want to use it to avoid joins between subclass tables, and it doesn't do the job the way they expect.  Specifically, if you have an A->B class hierarchy, and A is marked `EXPLICIT`, queries on A will retrieve B instances as well because they are "...subclasses mapped".

The way this annotation is meant to be used is, I believe, to have B marked `EXPLICIT`.  Then queries on A will return *only* instances of A, not just for objects that are actually of type A, but also for objects of type B, with only shared fields filled in.  This lets the annotation be used for the [lightweight pattern](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/LightweightClass).

**So my question is this:**  Aside from enabling the lightweight pattern, are there other good use cases for this annotation?  As a secondary question, is there any documentation on how it interacts with the various `InheritanceType` values, specifically joined subclass and table per class?